# couldn't add glassfish4 server in netbean 7.4

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I installed netbean 7.4 with glassfish4. I can see glassfish server 4 under server tab in service. It working nicely. I have want to register server through remot domain. I can't connect with remote domain. Remote domain is working properly and I can access web admin interface. With glassfish 3 and netbean 7.0. I added remote domain and works nicely. Is there any problem with netbean 7.4? How I can access remote server?